# CONVERT_FROM function in apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

I am able to query over HBase using Drill & convert data into the text from bytes.

Sample data in HBase table "table1":

```
row1       column=cf:a, timestamp=1447829041294, value=value1
```

Query I tried:

```
SELECT CONVERT_FROM(t.row_key, 'UTF8') AS id, CONVERT_FROM(t.`cf`.`a`, 'UTF8') AS col1 from hbase.`table1` t;
```

Using CONVERT_FROM for every field is not that good.

Is there any other way for this so that I don't need to use this function for every field?

Comment: Why is this not that good? The data in hbase is stored as binary, you're converting to UTF-8. If you don't like typing it every time, might I suggest making a [view](http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-view-command/)?

Comment: @ChrisMatta _this is not good_ because say I have 50 columns. First, I need to know data types for all the fields, second imagine a single select * query written in 30-40 lines. Isn't is bad?

Comment: I'm assuming you're going to know the data types of your columns, so figuring that out isn't too hard. I don't see how the number of lines in a select query relates to how good/bad it is... Drill supports views, which act like tables so instead of typing `select t.c1, t.c2, ..., t.c50 from...` you can create a view and simply `select * from myview;` So I would suggest you figure out the column types and then use `create view as` to build a view and avoid having to type all the columns.